# Case Sensitivity

Tags: php, case

i found a php search script online that works great for me. im having a problem with case sensitivity though. this search is linked to an html form input and will only return results that match the case searched. is there a way around this?

```
<?php
   //////////////////////
  // © Nadav Ami 2009 //
 //     Version 1.2  //
 //     Edited By  //
 //    Geoff Bolton //
//////////////////////


function scandir_r($dir){
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".", ".."));
$arr = array();
    foreach($files as $file){
    $arr[] = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        if(is_dir($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)){
        $arr = array_merge($arr, scandir_r($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file));
        }
    }
return($arr);
}

$dirname = "./";
$findme = "/".preg_quote($_POST["search"], "/")."/";
$files = preg_grep($findme, scandir_r($dirname));
if(sizeof($files)){
    foreach($files as $file){
    $_file = $dirname.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    echo "<a href=\"$_file\">$file</a><br/>";
    }
}
else{
echo "Nothing was found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php), [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and, of course, JS at client side.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i have no knowledge of php at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case-insensitive search. It's demonstrated in the first example of preg_match (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and should also work for `preg_grep`. so this should do the trick:

```
// [...]
$findme = "/".preg_quote($_POST["search"], "/")."/i";
// [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! that worked perfecly. the other problem i have is when files are indexed they include the full file path for example home/images/image.png. is there a way to ommit this so it results "image.png" i looked at the basename function but cant implement it

Comment: That is a complete different question and I have not tried, but I think you can use the `basename()` function to solve it: `echo "<a href=\"$_file\">".basename($file)."</a><br/>\n";`. If this is not what you want, I recommend to ask this in a new question.